# How can I get the URL from route's name in c# using asp.net mvc and the razor template engine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to get the url for a known route name inside of a razor template.

Here is my partial view

```
@model ScripterEngine.ViewModels.CampaignViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">

    function logTime(stage, status, async){

        var target = "@UrlHelper.RouteUrl("timetracker.clockin")";

        var postData =
        {
            'campaign_id': @Model.id,
            'agent_id': is_system_agentid.value,
            'log_id': is_attr_calldata.tracker_id,
            'stage_name': stage
        };

        if( status == 'out'){
            target = "@UrlHelper.RouteUrl("timetracker.clockout")";
        }

        if( async !== false){
            async = true;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: target,
            data: postData,
            async: async,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){

                alert('clock ' + status + ' failed!' + jqXHR.status );
            },
            success: function(data){

                if(data && data.id && status != 'out'){
                    is_attr_calldata.tracker_id  = data.id;
                }

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Here is my route mapping

```
        //Timetracker - ClockIn
        routes.MapRoute(
            "timetracker.clockin",
            "timetracker/clockin",
            new { controller = "TimeTracker", action = "ClockIn" }
        );

        //Timetracker - ClockOut
        routes.MapRoute(
            "timetracker.clockout",
            "timetracker/clockout",
            new { controller = "TimeTracker", action = "ClockOut" }
        );
```

However, I get a compilation error after I start the program and navigate to the route .

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0120: An object reference is required for
>   the non-static field, method, or property
>   'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.RouteUrl(string)'

The error point at this line

```
var target = "@UrlHelper.RouteUrl("timetracker.clockin")";
```

How can I properly get the Url from a giving route name?

Comment: @NikolaiDante yes. that should not matter. the outside double quotes are plain and the inside will be executed at the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UrlHelper` is exposed on a view as `@Url` - the code for `WebViewPage` has:

```
public UrlHelper Url { get; set; }
```

Try:

```
var target = '@Url.RouteUrl("timetracker.clockin")';
```

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. Since this return only the URI and does not include the domain do I need to add a base tag to my html?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't, it makes deploying through over environments (dev, test, staging, production etc..) more tricky. Unless you have a compelling reason to?

Comment: I just want to make sure that I can put this URI any where in the site and it will take the user to the URL

Comment: you _should_ be ok... I've never had to use base in an app, but YMMV. :-) It _should_ work out the right relative url.